# Cannot access XAMPP (1.7.3) from my local network

Tags: xampp, port, ip, apache, forward

I am running XAMPP 1.7.3 on windows 7. My problem is that when I try to access my server (localhost) from another computer, the server does not respond. For example, [on my computer] when I type in 'http://localhost', my pages come up. However, when I try accessing 'http://192.168.0.102' from my computer, nothing happens. When I type in my external IP, nothing shows up, but when add HTTPS to the external IP, my Linksys WRT54GS config page shows up, asking for a password. I have already tried port forwarding and a local "static IP", and no luck, other than my local IP never changing. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I have my XAMPP installation configured. Maybe it will work for you.

- Open C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
- Add a VirtualHost block for each site you are running:

Apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot C:/path/to/website/files
    ServerName exampledomain.dev

    <Directory "C:/path/to/website/files">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- Add a line to your hosts

  127.0.0.1   exampledomain.dev
- On the connecting computer's host file:

  192.168.0.102   exampledomain.dev

You can easily access your hosts file by using ctrl+r and running 
`notepad %SYSTEMROOT%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: I had to add a space after each < character, because the code formatting wouldn't work. You'll probably have to remove those spaces for the config to work.